# Screenshot on failed tests using Junit 5 Selenium parallel execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, junit5

I would like to take a screenshot every single time test fails or if multiple tests then multiple screenshots of course.

So far I understand that I can just wrap my single test with a `try catch` block and proceed taking a screenshot, however I would not want to wrap it in every test I have. I want it to apply to all of them without wrapping each one, do I have to do that in my setup?

```
public class WebDriverSettings
{

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected String TARGET_URL;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().addArguments("window-size=1920x1480"));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        loginToEnvironment();
    }
}

public class LoginServiceTest extends WebDriverSettings
{
    private LoginModal loginModal;
    private AccountApi accountApi;
    private Credentials credentials;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        super.setUp();
        credentials = new SignUp();
        accountApi = new AccountApi(credentials);
        accountApi.createAccount();
        loginModal = new HomePage(driver).acceptCookies().clickOnMyAccountTab().switchToLoginTab();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessfullyLogin()
    {
        try
        {
            accountApi.createAccount();
            assertFalse(loginModal.login(credentials).getMyAccountName().getText().isEmpty());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File("path"));
            } catch (IOException ioException)
            {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
            accountApi.closeAccount();
        }
    }
}
```

Solution advised by Jeff

So creating Util package and adding a class that would be responsible for creating a screenshot also it would generate random name but needs to be refactored i just made it quickly to make it work

```
public class ScreenShotCreator {

    public static void takeScreenShot(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File(fileNameGenerator()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not make a screenshot");
        }
    }

    // creating this for test purposes , need to use string builder instead to append it instead of adding it
    private static String fileNameGenerator() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm");
        String path = ".....";
        return path + "screenshot" + formatter.format(new Date()) + " " + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10) + ".png";
    }
```

Then before closing it down  just call the created method

```
@AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        ScreenShotCreator.takeScreenShot(driver);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code that takes a screenshot? In the title and beginning of your question you ask how to take a screenshot on fail but in the end you ask how to take a screenshot during `clickMyCardsTab()` to see how the UI looks. These are two different questions... please edit your question to make it clear what you are looking for (maybe break this question up into two separate questions) and add the code relevant to the updated question... where you tried to take a screenshot, tried to take a screenshot on fail, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I would suggest is

1. Create a method to take a screenshot and put that in a Utils class and call it when you want to take a screenshot. This will make taking a screenshot a lot easier because all the code lives in one place and can be easily called from anywhere.
2. Create a `tearDown()` method, if you don't have one already. Looks like it would go in the `WebDriverSettings` class from your currently posted code. Mark it with an `@AfterEach` annotation and then detect a failed test case and if it failed, take a screenshot.

   If you aren't sure how to do that, there's a class in JUnit 4.9 and later called [`TestWatcher`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html) that you can use. There are lots of examples on the web on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you Jeff i thought about making separate class that would take a screenshot , now just need to make random generated name since its all running paralell , and yes tear down makes sense , will try and see if it works, thank you bud

Comment: Hey bud, added quick solution so others can review, will refactor later but thanks.

Comment: @Prozorov For the randomly generated name, you should be able to get the test name through JUnit and then you can append a date/time stamp to ensure that you get a unique name for your screenshot.

Comment: what you mean by generated name through Junit , Junit wont apply any name there since you purposely need to throw a name to the path , so if there is a way that junit provide random name  please let me know

Comment: actually i have a problem , the tear down is called even if test passes so the screenshot is taken anyway, so i need to figure out how to screen it only on exception

Comment: I didn't say that JUnit would create the random name for you, I said that you can use JUnit to get the currently running test and append that to the current date/time stamp to get a unique name, not a random name. For example <testName><yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss><.jpg> would be "LoginServiceTest.2021.02.20.17.47.00.jpg" as an example screenshot name. You should probably do some googling... there are a LOT of resources including already answered SO questions on how to get the name of the current running test using JUnit.

Comment: Yes, that's why I stated in my answer, "detect a failed test case and if it failed, take a screenshot." In `tearDown()` you need to detect if the test case failed. There are lots of existing resources on how to do this on the web.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229005/discussion-between-prozorov-and-jeffc).

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was to create this extension:

```
package some.thing;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterTestExecutionCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Screenshotter implements AfterTestExecutionCallback {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        Screenshotter.driver = driver;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if (context.getExecutionException().isPresent()) { // if the test execution has failed
            String baseFileName = context.getRequiredTestClass().getSimpleName() + "-"
                    + context.getRequiredTestMethod().getName()
                    + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("-yyMMdd-HHmmss"));
            File targetFile = new File("somewhere/" + baseFileName + ".png");
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            Files.copy(scrFile.toPath(), targetFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            targetFile.setReadable(true, false);
            LOG.info("Screenshot saved to " + targetFile.toPath());
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply it to the relevant test class like so:

```
@ExtendWith(Screenshotter.class)
public class SomeTest {
    ...
    @BeforeAll
    public void initialize() {
        ...
        Screenshotter.setDriver(driver);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```